# Best way to make connection with rubber contact pad

Tags: pcb, raspberry-pi, telephone

I dismantled a push-button telephone and I am want to control it using a Raspberry Pi (A+) to trigger the button presses.  The phone has a grid of 12 (+2 special buttons) contacts that correspond to the dial numbers.  Normally the rubber domes would make connection when the button is pushed, but I want to find a way to close the circuit somehow using a Raspberry Pi.  Below is a picture of the PCB.  There's a potential difference of ~4.1 volts across the contacts.

[image: Phone PCB]

I also need some way to close/open the latch that the handset would normally rest on, pictured below at SW2.  It has the expected ~48 volts running through it, so it's waaaaay too much to directly control with a Pi.  I plan on soldering a relay in there, as the contacts are easier to work with on the underside there.  Unless there's a better way to do that.

[image: Hook]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more difficult than you may have thought. The telephone circuit uses 48 V to power the telephone, dialing, and on/off-hook signalling and speech circuits. It also uses up to 100 V AC for ringing signal. They also get the odd whack of lightning induced current. You can't connect your micro directly to it.

[image]

*Figure 1. DTMF tone matrix. The fourth column is defined but rarely implemented.*

The keypad switches the [DTMF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual-tone_multi-frequency_signaling) (dual-tone multiple-frequency) tone generator chip. The buttons are generally arranged in a 3 x 4 grid which is scanned by powering the rows (or columns) in turn and reading back the columns (or rows). In your photo I can see the traces running to the chip. The significance of this for you is that neither pole of the contact switch is grounded so you can't use a simple pull-down transistor arrangement to do the switching. You'll have to use miniature relays or opto-isolators (taking care to get the polarity right). Meanwhile, see if you can get a part number from the chip, read the datasheet and learn from that.

The whole project might be a bad idea!

> Best way to make connection with rubber contact pad?

You don't. You make contact with the PCB. You would need to attach wires to the chip pins. Each relay / opto would short out a row and a column.

Comment: I'm far from an expert and don't trust my soldering abilities, so I plan on taking the really roundabout solution of mounting a set of really small solenoids above the PCB and physically touching the contacts with the little black bits on the rubber sheet.